# Can an Android Webview keeps alive on background?

Tags: android, webview

I have the following situation and I dont know exactly what it could be:

I have a webview in my app wich among other things periodically sends and ajax request to a server which response may trigger the play of a sound.

This work perfect, the only weird thing is that, sometimes when the app is on background the sound is played, it would seem that the webview is still executing, but I thought that it would be killed when the app goes to background.

The most weird thing is that sometimes the app has been on background for several hours before the sound is played(so I assume that it is restarted somehow)

I think that the issue is related with the RAM and the system deciding to it free or not. Because it happens mostly in newer devices which are used mostly for testing(a lot of RAM) and also in old devices with fewer RAM it does not happen.

Now, is possible to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to stop all the periodic actions your application does on OnPause and start them  again on OnResume. Override these methods on your fragment and it should work.